# Is there a way to clear memory of Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am noticing that Zeppelin is consuming a lot of memory even when I am not running any paragraph. It seems, it caches some data in the memory somehow. Is there any way to clear such memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the following URL: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/104408/how-to-clear-values-in-zeppelin-notebook.html

> Zeppelin stores [cached variables] in a file called note.json. This file is usually stored inside of a directory (the note's ID is usually in the URL for the note, and is the subdirectory name) on the Zeppelin home server, and can be edited in a text editor where you can remove the values/paragraphs if you so require.
>
> Here is a good post showing how to do it: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/24254/zeppelin-how-to-remove-results-cache-from-notebook.html

This should help clear up some of the memory for you.

Comment: OK, if they are stored in file, then why it is consuming more RAM. I want to clear the RAM usage.

Comment: @MetallicPriest the cached variables are stored in memory. They are referenced by this json file. Try deleting them from here to see if this helps.